# Email alert when page is open

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way in asp.net that when my page is open on web then an email alert with username should be generate so that i have information that which one is accessing my page

I changed the code like bellow

```
 Public Sub SendMail(ByVal id As String)
        Dim message = New MailMessage()
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        message.From = New MailAddress("adeel.aslam0@gmail.com")
        message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com"))
        message.Subject = "user access page"
        message.Body = "Your Message"
        ' add id here
        Dim client = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        client.Send(message)
    End Sub
```

and in web.config like this

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="adeel.aslam0@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
      port="587" userName ="adeel.aslam0@gmail.com" password="pass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Yes! Send an email in the Page_Load method. But seriously do you want an email each time sometime accesses your page ? How about Google Analytics ? Or create a simple database that will track the information and you can view the database ?

Comment: I wanto email alert with name of the logged in user to my specific email addres.have u any example or code to do this.I have open Id login system

Comment: @user1065397 also look at your profile faqs. no answers no vote cast, seems like you come here to get answers only... so you should probably need to work on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do something similar..

Modify your `web.config` file to send emails

e.g. This use gmail settings

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourMailId@gmail.com ">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
      port="587" userName ="yourmail@gmail.com" password="yourpassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

And in your `page_load`

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                var user =  HttpContext.Current.User;
                if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                    SendMail(id.ToString());
                }   
            }
        }

public void SendMail(string id)
{
var message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress("yourmail");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("tomail"));
message.Subject= "user access page";
message.Body = "Your Message";// add id here

var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
}
```

if you using `vb` try something like this.

This way, you will not need to change your `web.config`

```
Dim mailobject As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()  
Dim myCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourmail@gmail.com", "password")  

mailobject.To.Add("tomail")  
mailobject.Subject = "User Access The Page"  

mailobject.From = New  System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("frommail")  
mailobject.IsBodyHtml = True  
mailobject.Body = "Your Message"  

Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")  
SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False  
SmtpMail.EnableSsl = True  
SmtpMail.Credentials = myCred  
SmtpMail.Port = 587
SmtpMail.Send(mailobject)
```

Comment: if you get a fair amount of visitors, google will block your Gmail account if you to this. You cannot send more than 500 mails per 24 hours.... http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=1a01814e7b919603&hl=en

Comment: @Pleun: I'm not asking him to use gmail settings. Its just an **example** which anyone can understand

Comment: I know (I upvoted your answer btw) just want to illustrate the fact that in real life this will cause all kind of problems and it is not really something you want to do.

Comment: Sir Thanks for the Reply but its dnt sending the mail when page loads

Comment: @user1065397 it should send the mail when page load..whats the problem you have? add a breakpoint in the pageload and run the application. see what happens?

Comment: page loads successfully but no email receives on my email accoutn.Where to add brekpoint?

Comment: @user1065397: is that same code you using in your application, if so change your **message.Body = "Your Message" ' add id here  to message.Body = "Your Message"**

Answer (score 0):

Fair question. But you really do not want to do this unless you have a very limited amount of visitors. See the answer above on how to do it.

Better write everything into a table and send yourself a digest at certain interval per hour/day. This way you can also do some reporting afterwards using that table.

Comment: Actually sir i am using OpenId to acces my web page and when open id is authenticated from google the username appears as  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawk3_FDBplKN9ONWKPXVp8YRaTtM92J2YsY how can i translate it into actual username

Comment: That you should post as a new question.